# Indexing in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I would like to convert this code to tf friendly one:

```
left_indices = []
right_indices = []
#y_true.shape is (batch, height, width, channel)
y_true = y_true.numpy()
for i in range(y_true.shape[0]):
    if y_true[i,0,0,:] > 0:
        left_indices.append(i)
        y_true[i,0,0,:] = 0
    elif y_true[i,0,1,:] >0:
        right_indices.append(i)     
        y_true[i,0,0,:] = 0
```

This is a part of my custom loss function and I want to access values on the corresponding indices and set them to zero.
I get the error:

```
'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

After googling I have found that I can add run_eagerly=True to my model.compile(). It works but I get a warning at every step:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:11 out of the last 11 calls to <function _apply_all_reduce.<locals>._all_reduce 
at 0x14ec2fcbcc10> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the exce                                                 
ssive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2)                                                  
passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (                                                 
1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has experimen                                                 
tal_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument shapes that can avoid unnecessary retraci
```

Comment: What are you doing with left_indices and righ_indices?

Comment: @AloneTogether I am doing semantic segmentation and I have 3 imbalanced classes of images. 
Setting class_weight in model.fit does not work, so I wanted to manually weight loss for some classes.
I passed the information to which class an image belongs by setting a certain pixel white [0,0,:] or [0,1,:]. 
Left_indices are for class 1, right_indices are for class 2.
Few lines below when I calculate loss for every image inside the batch, I access these images and edit their loss before returning it.